# What is the best practice with regards to type consistency for returning a result, error, or warning in Python?

Tags: python, code-documentation

This might be answered elsewhere, but I had trouble finding a good "Googlable" phrasing to this question. I have a Python program I'm writing where the lead has requested that all exits from the program occur in the main body - which makes sense. However, that leaves me at an impasse because if you're following best practice for typing in Python you typically have something like:

```
def myfunc(arg1: int, arg2: str) -> dict
```

However, say that in myfunc you call out to a webserver to retrieve a list. A connection failure is something you want to be fatal whereas a lack of results is just a warning. What is the best practice for how to return those results? The way I'm currently doing it is returning an empty list if there are no results, the correct result if it works, and `None` for error and then I just check for the empty list or `None` after the function call. However, this then means my return type could be `None` which is not of type `dict`. Is that the accepted best practice or is there a more correct way per the PEPs?

Comment: You should probably throw an Exception for an actual error condition and you can have different classes of Exception for different types of errors.

Comment: I don't think the "duplicate question" is super accurate. As a quick suggestion - if the connection fails, then let it raise the exception, don't try catch it (alternatively, catch it and treat it the same as "no results"). If there are no results, return an empty dict. If there are results, return the dict as per normal. You want your function to have the same type of output no matter what happens.

Comment: @Peter - That was pretty much what I took away from that other answer. Basically if you want to communicate that sort of additional information use an exception. Depending on the granularity it may have to be a custom exception.